# Nginx on FreeBSD: fcgiwrap.sock permission denied

Tags: freebsd, configuration, nginx, socket, fastcgi

I'm trying to setup nginx and cgit on FreeBSD but nginx can't access `/var/run/fcgiwrap/fcgiwrap.sock`.

In my `/etc/rc.conf` I already set `fcgiwrap_user="www"`, and `www` is also the user nginx runs as.

When I make `fcgiwrap.sock` owned by `www` by performing `chown www /var/run/fcgiwrap/fcgiwrap.sock`, everything works the way I want.

However this is of course not the proper way to do this, and it will only last until reboot.

I was under the assumption that setting `fcgiwrap_user="www"` would also determine this.

Am I missing something?

**Update:**

I noticed that when I use `service fcgiwrap start` or `restart`, the message `Starting fcgiwrap` is followed by `chmod: /var/run/fcgiwrap/fcgiwrap.sock: No such file or directory`. However `/var/run/fcgiwrap/fcgiwrap.sock` does exist afterwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The RC script is located at `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/fcgiwrap`.

Looking at the code, `fcgiwrap_user` sets the owner of the process running the daemon (default `root`).

You need to set `fcgiwrap_socket_owner="www"` to set the owner of the socket.

Comment: Ah I see! That did the trick, thank you. How come most sources on this topic only mention `fcgiwrap_user`? Could it be that this has been changed since then?

Comment: There is a lot of bad advice out there :-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Richard Smith also worked for me but in my case I also had to set `fcgiwrap_socket_group="www"`.
These settings seem to be new because earlier it was sufficient to set `fcgiwrap_user="www"`.

Comment: That is nice to know too! Thanks for pointing it out.